# Display dates attached to events in a database with C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database that contains events as an ICollection. Each event has a number of different dates. Some of these events are Exhibitions and run over two weeks. How could I list just the first date from all my exhibitions

so as an example:

```
Exhibition 1:  11/12/2015    

Exhibition 2:  21/01/2016
```

I have the following code, but not sure how to group using C#

```
dates = client.GetEventInstances()
   .Where(x => x.Details.TypeOfEvent.Contains("Exhibition")  &&  x.StartDate == DateTime.Now)
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx

Comment: Question lacks tags and details. Are you using EF? What is `Exhibition`? Without such details answer would be "use `GroupBy`", but you see how good this answer is?

Comment: Do you actually need to group by?  Or are you just interested in the actual dates and can use [`.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: You might want to use [`DateTime.Today`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `DateTime.Now`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
client.GetEventInstances()
      .Where(x => x.Details.TypeOfEvent.Contains("Exhibition"))
      .OrderBy(x => x.StartDate))
      .First()
```

Comment: thanks, would I need to parse dates to DateTime to display a date on  page?

Comment: Depends of type you have in your Event object for date and type control on page expects...